# can not connect Pentaho report designer with MySQL database

Tags: charts, pentaho, mysql-connector

I would also ask if Pentaho support multi-source in one report(Ex: a chart takes its data from two different databases )

I am trying to use Pentaho to create some report charts, when i setup the configuration and click on test, it generates this error:

```
Error connecting to database [sqltest] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed.
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed.
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver


    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:415)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:353)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:306)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:294)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:84)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2459)
    at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:541)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingButton$OnClickRunnable.run(SwingButton.java:58)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1072)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1650)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1602)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1013)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1003)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingDialog.show(SwingDialog.java:238)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:254)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.ConnectionPanel$AddDataSourceAction.actionPerformed(ConnectionPanel.java:252)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1072)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1650)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1602)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1013)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1003)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.setVisible(CommonDialog.java:281)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.performEdit(CommonDialog.java:193)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:788)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:71)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.report.AddDataFactoryAction.actionPerformed(AddDataFactoryAction.java:78)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed.
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:474)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:399)
    ... 123 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:467)
    ... 124 more

Hostname       : localhost
Port           : 3306
Database name  : alger_fa
```

Answer (score 2):

No Pentaho does-not support multi-source in one report..

have you placed this jar file mysql-connector-java-5.1.10 under below location

> \pentaho_report_designer_working\report-designer\lib\jdbc\

if not then download and keep that jar file into above mention location , your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, well i placed the MySQL connector still it did not work for me. As a matter of fact i need a reporting tool that support multi-source in one report, do you know a tool for that (Open source is preferred)

Comment: it has to work.. after placing jar file re-start report designer..
No i have to idea about such toll.. wait for some-one else to answer..

Comment: i did restart the designer.. anyway do you know anything about a JDBC driver that allows executing a SQL statement over multiple databases from different vendors.. That will help me to avoid multi-source reporting tool

Comment: I have placed jar file at `C:\Pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\lib` But, still i am unable to get Mysql connection option in my designer tool.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue...even I have placed the jar file in lib but no luck

Comment: @sandeepsure after putting jar files you have to restart your data-integration.

Comment: @GhostRider have you restarted data-integration after keeping your jar file in lib?

Comment: @WorkingHard.. yes. I have restarted it several times and I have even tried restarting my machine. I have reinstalled MySQL and now I am getting 
'Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
The statement (1) has no open cursor.'

Comment: @GhostRider no need to do it several times..
provide me all the details, pentaho version, what and all things you have configure in environment variable if you are using windows.

Comment: @WorkingHard.. I am using PDI version 5.2.0.0. jdk1.7.0_79 and environment variables set for jdk bin dir and  path of mysql like this "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"... Let me know if you need any other info in specific

Comment: @GhostRider you have missed JAVA_HOME...
please check this link and set the path..
no need to catalina path..
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Ogf7_8jjUUZHMyR2w3TU9FUEU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @WorkingHard.. Thanks for your time...My issue got fixed. Here is the link to my question and solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570549/error-connecting-to-database-using-class-org-gjt-mm-mysql-driver-the-statemen