# Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver) The statement (1) has no open cursor

Tags: mysql, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am working on Pentaho Data Integration tool version 5.2. I am trying to connect to data base using 'Table Input' step. but when I test the connection in this step it is giving me the below error message. I am able to connect to DB using the MySQL workbench. I have placed the '`mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin`' file in the `libext` forlder.

do I need to downgrade my connector jar file? if yes my SQL version is 5.6 so can some one let me know the compatible connector jar version for this SQL Server version?

```
Error connecting to database [myLedger] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
The statement (1) has no open cursor.


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
The statement (1) has no open cursor.


    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:427)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:361)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:314)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:302)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2685)
    at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:546)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:389)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:318)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:116)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:59)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog$4.widgetSelected(BaseStepDialog.java:740)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInputDialog.open(TableInputDialog.java:435)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:124)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:8720)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:3027)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDoubleClick(TransGraph.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1310)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7931)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9202)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
    The statement (1) has no open cursor.

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:572)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:410)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The statement (1) has no open cursor.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:777)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1260)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.fetchRowsViaCursor(MysqlIO.java:3838)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CursorRowProvider.fetchMoreRows(CursorRowProvider.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CursorRowProvider.hasNext(CursorRowProvider.java:303)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:6459)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.loadServerVariables(Connection.java:4059)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.initializePropsFromServer(Connection.java:3778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2608)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1509)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:554)
    ... 52 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. the `useCursorFetch` was set to `true` which I have changed to `false` in the `Options` menu in the left side panel of Data Base connection.

Comment: i don't see any `useCursorFetch` in menu `option`. :(

Comment: which version of PDI are you using ?